# Why does Java's HashSet have an underlying HashMap, not the other way around?

Tags: data-structures, java

Why does Java's `HashSet` have an underlying `HashMap`, not the other way around? `HashMap` could have contained an internal `HashSet` of `Map.Entry`s, and `HashSet` wouldn't have stored a reference to an internal "dummy" `Object` per each element (while implementing the hashtable data structure itself). Is there (could there be) some idea behind this design that I don't understand?

> A `HashSet` of `Map.Entrys` would hash both the key and the value, so it would be impossible to access the value for a given key unless you already knew the value.
>
> *–a user of a [sibling site](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/why-does-javas-hashset-have-an-underlying-hashmap-not-the-other-way-around)*

Why couldn't `HashSet` hash just the key?

> At that point what you're describing is just a regular hashmap, isn't it?
>
> *–another user on the same site*

Ok. But there's no way it's the most efficient solution to pair each element with a meaningless object reference, is there?

```java
// I simplified Java's actual HashSet code to convey the gist of its design

public class HashSet<E> {
    private HashMap<E,Object> map;
    private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
    
    public HashSet() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return map.containsKey(o);
    }

    public void add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I'm not sure that questions that are specific to a particular programming language, like a question about the Java standard library, are on-topic here.  See our [help/on-topic].  Any community votes? 2. "Why does Java's HashSet have an underlying HashMap, not the other way around?" - I don't know what that means.  What does that mean, and why do you believe it is true?

Comment: 3.  I don't understand what alternative design you have in mind.  4. Please ask only one question per post.  Rather than listing this as a Q&A or an back-and-forth with other anonymous users, it might be better to explain what reasons you've considered and why you've rejected them.

Comment: (Take the interfaces from `java.util` (even `AbstractMap/Set`) and implement what you think more appropriate.)

Comment: I think this question belongs to stack overflow.  also you can check following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235546/why-does-hashset-implementation-in-sun-java-use-hashmap-as-its-backing

Comment: @mathboy's link is correct, there are many better ways to implement it: write hashset and hashmap separately, or inherit hashmap from hashset.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, you are saying that Java implements HashSet using HashMap, with NULL values, and are asking why you couldn't implement HashMap using (an alternate implementation of) HashSet?

If this is the case, then consider: This alternate implementation of HashSet would most likely NOT store the hashed elements of the set in a record containing both a reference to the set element AND a reference to an associated value, since there would be no associated value.  How would one then implement HashMap using this?  I.e how would one add the missing value reference slot to the element record?

Comment: No, no, the values are references to an internal dummy `Object`. For instance, if you add a string "hello", `HashSet` would essentially perform this operation, `map.put("hello", emptyObject)`, given `map` is an underlying `HashMap` and `emptyObject` is `new Object()`